# How to create a variable List

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

I need, given "n", create a list {a1,a2,...,an}. For example:
Given n=3, the list that must be created is composed by the symbolic variables {a1,a2,a3}.
Sorry if this question is simple. Does anybody knows how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Use e.g. `Array[a, 3]`. This will give you indexed variables which should serve the same purpose as those you look for.

Comment: `"a" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[10]` or `Table["a" <> IntegerString[i, 10], {i, 1, 10}]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, for n=5

```
Table[Symbol["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 5}]
```

but consider that in any case it may not be optimal for what you need to do. If you want to share what you are planning to use this list for, we may help you with a better construct.

Comment: Thanks very much Fraccalo. Helped quite a lot. I am trying to manipulate equations based on Feynman diagrams.  But I won't bother you with this. You have just helped me a lot. Thank You again. Best wishes,  J.R.Descardeci

Answer (score 5):

You might also try with:

```
Table[Unique["a"], {n}]
```

The advantage and disadvantage of this is that generated variables are unique - there will be no conflict with but also no reuse of existing ones.

Note: depending on what you do, you might also want to `Remove` such generated variables after they are no longer needed, to avoid leaking memory for unused symbols.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by MarcoB, indexed variables are highly convenient and less prone to error or difficulties. They can be **displayed** in any manner that you desire using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html).

```
n = 5;

list = Array[a, n];
```

To display as you show

```
Format[a[n_]] := Symbol["a" <> ToString[n]]

list
```

[image]

```
To display as subscripts

Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n]

list
```

[image]

Or with a specified style

```
Format[a[n_]] := Style[Subscript[a, n], Bold, Italic, Blue]

list
```

[image]